# Puppeteer Error: No Node Found for selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to click on an input element through Puppeteer after going to the URL I requested
I input a quantity by using

```
await page.type('#bidamount_temp', bidAmount);
```

Puppeteer is not complaining about this error:
However after inputting a value into the field; i want the puppeteer to click on this button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Place Bid " class="buttonspb" style="font-size:15px; margin-top:-2px;" onclick="return url_check();">
```

So I use this in my node.js code:

```
await Promise.all([
  page.click('input[value="Place Bid "]'),
  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
]);
```

However it is giving me an error of :

Error: Error: No node found for selector: input[value="Place Bid"]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without seeing the page you're working with, it's hard to help because the selector looks fine shown as-is. On a real site, JS may be hiding it, `click` could have visibility issues (it's often necessary to use `page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('input[value="Place Bid "]').click())`), or many other potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the error message that it strips the space from button value: you have `"Place Bid "`, puppeteer converts it into `"Place Bid"`. You should use another selector to access the button, for example `input[type="submit"].buttonspb`

Comment: I've realized, after I log in I cannot call another function and pass in page, but must run all the Puppeteer methods in the same function or else its not navigating in the same browser.. So now it works since I put all the code lines in the same function.